# Compare two arrays in php (duplicate)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");

$array2 = array("foo", "bar");
```

I want to show my result by comparing two arrays. If `array2` any item match with `array1` item then those item skip.

Comment: http://php.net/array_diff

Answer (score 2):

You can use the array_diff() function.

It takes at least two arguments, the array to compare from (we'll call it `$array1`), then at least one array to compare to (assuming one array per the question, we'll call this `$array2`).

Therefore, the code for what you want is virtually all there already, you just need to do the following:

```
$array1 = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
$array2 = array("foo", "bar");

$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);

foreach($diff as $v) {
    echo $v . ' ';
}
```

It will return an array containing any values in the first array that are not in any of the other arrays given.

See the PHP documentation for more info: http://www.php.net/array_diff